# Java closing connections and findbugs

Tags: java, database, findbugs

In our code we usually use the following pattern:

```
Connection conn;
try{
    conn = getConnection();
    //Do databasey stuff
}catch(Exceptions that get thrown){
}finally{
    try{
        conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        logger.error("Failed to cleanup database connection",ex);
    }
}
```

However findbugs doesn't like this. Since conn.close() can throw an exception then the connection isn't guaranteed to be closed.
Is findbugs being too pedantic or is there a better way to close database connections.

Edit:
Added removed try catch around close.

Comment: -1 So put the try catch back in.  Editing it for brevity should be non-substantial.  Does your code validator have a problem with the uncaught exception or the connection not guaranteed to be closed?

Comment: Have added the try catch. Findbugs has issues with the above because, if an exception is thrown during conn.close() the connection will (presumably) remain open.

Comment: javac should be complaining about that code. If you do something daft, say, assign `conn` with `null`, then you have a potential NPE.

Comment: @Jim I suggest you look at my answer since I think it is a better one than the one you have currently selected.

Comment: try with resources will clean this all up and get rid of the problem ;)

Comment: Well, nothing can get rid of the problem of close() itself being broken if it can throw an exception. The docs don't say what that would actually mean, and they certainly don't say that the close operation still succeeds if it threw an exception. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you really want to be doing is to combine "The Elite Gentleman"'s answer with the `@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings( "OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION" )` annotation. FindBugs seems to only be happy if you the complete closing in method in the following manner (which is btw the preferred sequence for doing so):

```
...
}finally{
    try{ 
       resultSet.close();
    }catch( SqlException e ){
       //log error
    }finally{
       try{
          statement.close();
       }catch( SqlException e ){
          //log error
       }finally{
          try{
              connection.close();
          }catch( SqlException e ){
              //log error
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Which is very verbose and you probably don't want to do if for no other reason than the love of your carpal tunnel, thus you should use the `DBUtils.closeQuietly()` method (or create your own, your call). However, FindBugs doesn't recognise this (i.e. using the library or your own method) as properly closing the resources and issues you a warning. In this case it is clearly a [false positive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive#Type_I_error). Therefore must make sure its the only warning you are getting and then disable that specific warning for that method.

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings( "OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION" )
public void doStuff( final Connection connection ){
    try{
        //Do databasey stuff
    }catch( SqlException e ){
        //throw a glorious exception....
    }finally{
        DbUtils.closeQuietly( resultSet  );
        DbUtils.closeQuietly( statement  );
        DbUtils.closeQuietly( connection );
}
```

This way you clean up your resources with the few lines of code and avoid a FindBugs warning.

Answer (score 6):

There's already a utility that does what @duffymo mentioned: [DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) from Apache.

- `DbUtils.close(ResultSet);`
- `DbUtils.close(Statement);`
- `DbUtils.close(Connection);`

The [APIDocs](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/) shows all available methods.

---

**Update**

Here's an example:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbutils;


Connection conn;
try{
    conn = getConnection();
    //Do databasey stuff
} catch(Exception e){
    //throw a glorious exception....
} finally{
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn); //This hides the SQLException thrown by conn.close();
    //or 
    //DbUtils.close(conn);
}
```

---

Update: As suggested by ArtB, if you're finally closing resources and connections and findBugs is being a nagger, you can add the following annotation (on top of the method).

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings("OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION")
```

Comment: @duffymo, it's amazing why there's downvotes without explanation.

Comment: I think it should be banned actually.

Comment: FindBugs still seems to complain if you use DBUtils to do the closing.

Comment: @ArtB, are you closing the connection **quietly** or simple close (with caught exceptions) with DBUtil?

Comment: I am using `DBUtils.closeQuiety()`. The answer it turns out to be to add the annotation `@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings( "OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION" )`. I hope this gets voted up so people see it and not just left in the "more comments" link. Perhaps I should add it as a separate answer?

Comment: @ArtB, thanks for that. Kudos (+1) for your solution. What happens if you use `DBUtils.close()` method?

Comment: Basically FindBugs expects to see an explicit `try{ cxn.close() }catch{ /* handle */}` in the method itself. Otherwise it issues a warning.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman I just created a new answer anyway for visibility reasons... though I should have just asked you to update yours. *headdesk*

Comment: @edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings is deprecated at FindBugs-3.0.1

Comment: Please use ```edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings``` instead

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's a better way.

Create a static method that wraps the close in a try/catch:

```
public class DatabaseUtils
{
    public static void close(Connection c)
    {
        try
        {
            if (c != null)
            {
                c.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            // print or log stack trace
        }
    }

    // same for Statement and ResultSet
}
```

Comment: This is of course neater as it reduces repeatedly catching wherever connections are used. However I'm sure findbugs will still not be happy as an exception in the close will mean this remains open.

Comment: `// print or log stack trace` No, you should be throwing an exception (possible `SQLException`).

Comment: You don't necessarily want to throw an exception. While failing to close a connection is annoying it shouldn't necessarily cause things like transaction rollbacks.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - no, the whole point of this method is to prevent the exception from getting out.  You've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should encapsulate your close in a try block, but there is a cleverer way.

```
try {
    Connection c = getConnection();
    try {
        //do stuff
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //Catch exceptions
}
```

Comment: That's not "cleverer[sic]"; if an exception is thrown the connection will leak.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the finally block will still run if an exception is thrown in the inner try block. The only way the "connection will leak" is if the close statement itself throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a better way, but if you want to be sure that you catch everything, modify your pattern to this:

```
Connection conn;
try{
    conn = getConnection();
    //Do databasey stuff
}catch(Exceptions that get thrown){
}finally{
    try {
       conn.close();
    }
    catch  (SQLException se) {
       log.error("database problems...");
       // do more stuff if you need to
    }
}
```

Comment: The conn.close is inside a catch, have updated the question to add this.

Comment: @Stephen: there is always a better way; it's just not always obvious at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the whole thing by using something like Spring JDBCTemplate, which properly encapsulates all the open/close logic for you, simplifies your code, makes it cleaner and easier to read (as well as more likely to be correct).

An example, reading some columns from a table into a list of key-value pairs (yeah, ugly, but easy to understand):

```
        List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = jdbcTemplate.query(query,
                new RowMapper<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs,
                            int rownum) throws SQLException {
                        Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        int colIndex = 0;
                        row.put(CONTENTID_KEY, rs.getInt(++colIndex));
                        row.put(CONTENTTYPEID_KEY, rs.getInt(++colIndex));
                        row.put(DESCRIPTION_KEY, rs.getString(++colIndex));
                        row.put(CODE_KEY, rs.getString(++colIndex));
                        return row;
                    }
                });
```

For exception handling, see [spring jdbcTemplate how to catch exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916565/spring-jdbctemplate-how-to-catch-exception)