# spring jdbcTemplate how to catch exception?

Tags: java, jdbc

Everything is brilliant until I encounter place where I actually do need to catch exception. When I place

```
jdbcTemplate.query(something...)
```

in

```
try{}
```

block I get:

```
 Unreachable catch block for SQLException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body.
```

What do I do in this situation?

```
try{
    personIdReturnedByDb = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql, p.getEmail(),
            p.getName(), p.getSurname(), encPw, dateSql);
}

catch(SQLException sa){


}
```

Thank You,

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That's because `SQLException`, a checked exception, is not thrown by the any of the `JdbcTemplate.query(...)` methods ([javadoc link)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper%29). Spring translates this to one of the [DataAccessException](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html), which is more generic family of runtime exceptions, in order to abstract away any specific underlying database implementation.

Answer (score 8):

You should catch the JdbcTemplate exception

i.e.

```java
try
{
   // Your Code 
}
catch (InvalidResultSetAccessException e) 
{
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} 
catch (DataAccessException e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

InvalidResultSetAccessException is a DataAccessException so that no need to catch it in your case.
And DataAccessException is already a RuntimeException so that no need to throw a Runtime exception. 
But you should throw a specific exception of your application such as :

```
try
{
   // Your Code 
}
catch (DataAccessException e)
{
    throw new MyApplicationException("A problem occurred while retrieving my data", e);
}
```