# Spring Transaction propagation REQUIRED, REQUIRES_NEW

Tags: spring, transactions, propagation

in following code method `doService1()` update correct sql but `doService2()` sql has some issue , but when i call `doService()` it has to commit the `doService1()` update to DB even though the `doService2()` has a `sql exception` because `doService2()`  has a `REQUIRES_NEW Propagation` type but when i nun this `doService1()` update does not commit DB..

```
@Service public class DbClass {

      static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
              DbClass.class.getName());

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void doService(){
    doService1();
    doService2();
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void doService1(){
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "  update BATCHJOBSTATUS set PROCESSINGDATE = '20130322'  " ;
    int rowCount1 =  jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    System.out.println(" rowCount1 >" + rowCount1);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void doService2(){
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "  update aa set a_name = 'hhh' where a_id = 4 and " ;
    int rowCount1 =  jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    System.out.println(" rowCount2 >" + rowCount1);
}   
}
```

---

as your guys suggestion test in following way as well but still facing the same problem.
here i `doService2()` in a separate class but even though still have the same problem as above

```
@Service
public class DbClass {

  static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
          DbClass.class.getName());

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private DbClass2 dbClass2;

@Transactional
public void doService(){
    doService1();
    dbClass2.doService2();
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED )
public void doService1(){
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "  update BATCHJOBSTATUS set PROCESSINGDATE = '20130322'  " ;
    int rowCount1 =  jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    System.out.println(" rowCount1 >" + rowCount1);

    }


}


@Service
public class DbClass2 {


@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void doService2() {
    System.out.println("*******doService2*********`");

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    String sql = "  update aa set a_name = 'hhh' where a_id_ = 4  " ;

    int rowCount2 =  jdbcTemplate.update(sql);

    System.out.println(" rowCount2 >" + rowCount2);

}

}



<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring"/>

      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager1" proxy-target-class="true"/>



    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.8.121:1521:h3" />
        <property name="username" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>


  <bean id="txManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" >
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

    <bean id="batchJob" class="com.spring.jdbc.BatchJob">
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: The exception thrown is a runtimeException ? Could you try to put the doService2() line where there is the issue in a try/catch block ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem earlier and it was solved here : [Strange behaviour with @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767914/strange-behaviour-with-transactionalpropagation-propagation-requires-new)

Using default setting, there won't be any new transaction proxy created when you call `doService2()` from the same class, as a result your annotation is not user.

To avoid this issue you can put `doService2()` in another class or use aspectJ for transaction by declaring it like this : `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj"/>`

Best solution will depend on your application. (The second one here seems more appropriate)

Comment: Thanks for the reply..

when i use mode="aspectj" for above code committing happen for the doService1() this is fine,

but i m having another issue not when i changer doService2() annotation as @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY) this is not roll back the doService1() work,

please kindly advice me on this.

Comment: You mean that when you're using annotation @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY) on doService2(), an Exception thrown in doService2() is not rolling back doService1() ?

Comment: yes you are correct even though the Exception  in doService2() this will not rolling back doService1(),

Comment: I though that you wanted to avoid doService1() roll back ? Remove mode="aspectJ" and you should normally get a doService1() roll back with the mandatory propagation

Comment: However, if you want a doService1() roll back, the @Transactional over doService() is sufficient

Comment: yes you are correct if i have the @Transactional over doService()  that is sufficient, to roll back doService1(),

Comment: @user2241925 Is your problem now solved ? Or do you have other question ? If it's solved set your question as answered to avoid duplicate

Comment: yes you are correct if i have the @Transactional over doService()  that is sufficient, to roll back doService1(),

but my test is the understand how propagation REQUIRED, REQUIRES_NEW works in spring transaction environment.

Comment: that the reason i test my sample with propagation REQUIRED, REQUIRES_NEW and test its behavior. 

so when i have  REQUIRES_NEW in doService2() it is not roll back the doService1() that the my issue first time after 
i added  mode="aspectj" as your suggestion this problem was ok, but when i have MANDATORY in  doService2()  
doService1()  have to roll back but that not happen, please advice.

Comment: MANDATORY is just a way to be sure that you have an existing transaction opened otherwise it throws an error. Using simple @Transactional annotation does it rollback ?

Comment: yest with the @Transactional roll pack working but, when i have mode="aspectj"  for the MANDATORY  y it is not rollback ?

Comment: If with @Transactional and mode="aspectJ" doService1() is roll backing I have to admit that I don't know why it is not working with MANDATORY

Answer (score 4):

The call to `doService2()` probably doesn't have any transaction advice running on it because I'm assuming you're using a JDK dynamic proxy (interface proxy) instead of CGLIB based proxies. If you don't already know about how this works you might want to read: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-proxying .

If you're not using CGLIB (target-class proxying), it will never go through the Spring Transaction advisor when you call `doService2()` since it is invoking the method directly instead of going through the wrapper Spring creates for your service at startup time.

You can get your example working by moving `doService2()`  to a different service class then injecting it on to this service. That way you'll be going through the proxy and the transaction advice will run.

Otherwise, if you're ready to make a bigger change to your project, you could get your example to work as-is:
1) make sure CGLIB is in your classpath, and
2) turn on `proxy-target-class` , or force it to use CGLIB proxying so by getting rid of your service interface.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

If you're going to do this, make sure you're read through the first link :).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

i tried with your suggestion but no good result still have the same problem,


I tied with the separate class as well but that also not working as i expected .

Comment: Ahhh yeah. Looks like my memory was a little off on it :). T.Des's solution was right :).

Answer (score 1):

According to [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html)(Check section 10.5.6.1),the spring framework transaction will Rollback for only **RunTimeException**.
Not for other **checked** excpetions like `SqlException`.
So if you really want a rollback for this exception you have to specify it like below

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,rollbackFor=SQLException.class)
public void doService2(){
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "  update aa set a_name = 'hhh' where a_id = 4 and " ;
    int rowCount1 =  jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    System.out.println(" rowCount2 >" + rowCount1);
}
```

Try this and let me know if it works.

Also [this](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-propagation-tutorial) might help more.

Comment: I think the jdbcTemplate will wrap the SQLException in it's DataAccessException. And hence, users will only get DAE.http://stackoverflow.com/a/8916655